# How to get the position of a Layout relative to screen

Tags: android, android-animation

I want to animate a relative layout along the y-axis so I want to get its position on the y-axis. 
I tried many things like:

```
getY()
getTop()
getScreenLocation()
```

and so on, but everything is returning 0.

How can I find the position?

following is the code

```
ImageView advancetab = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
RelativeLayout advancelayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout2);
final ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(advancelayout, "Y", 
            advancelayout.getY(),advancelayout.getY()-100);
    anim.setDuration(1000);     
advancetab.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            anim.start();
        }
    });
```

When i clicked on the image then layout animate from 0,0 position to up.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my answer,

```
private int[] getViewLocations(View view) {
  int[] locations = new int[2];
  view.getLocationOnScreen(locations);
  return locations;
}
```

Use like this,

```
int[] locations = getViewLocations(yourcustomview);
int x = locations[0]; // x position of left
int y = locations[1]; // y position of top
```

Have fun.@.@

Answer (score 0):

I think, I am not sure that you have to make a  'canvas' and then use the options to find the position of x and y coordinates.. May be there are other options, but I have done this using this only.

Answer (score 0):

do write your code inside onwindowsfocuschange() of activity class...there you will get the parameters regarding your position on screen with getLocationonscreen() method of any view.